# Package mh cannot be found

Tags: packages, errors

> ! LaTeX Error: File `mh.sty' not
>   found.

However, `mh` is assuredly included in my TexLive2011 installation.

Why am I getting this error?

OS: Kubuntu 64-bit

Editor: TexWorks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`mh`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mh) is actually not a package, but a **bundle** (of packages). The bundle includes the following packages/components:

- [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn): Automatic line breaking of displayed equations
- [`empheq`](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq): EMPHasizing EQuations
- [`flexisym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flexisym): Symbol manipulation for [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn)
- [`mathstyle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathstyle): Manage mathematics typesetting style
- [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools): Mathematical tools to use with [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)
- [`mhsetup`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhsetup): The MH bundle "setup" function

You need to load whichever package you're interested in from the bundle via the regular `\usepackage` command, rather than `mh` itself.